# Javascript window.open(xxx, "download") creates a blank page while download prompt

Tags: safari, download, window.open

When I run window.open(file, "download") with safari, it opens a blank page while download prompt and the blank page stays there. I notice firefox opens a blank tab but it's close when download starts. Is there another javascript command/function that will work so there's no blank page opened in Safari?

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use `window.location = file` instead?

Redirecting to the file leads to the same behavior as clicking on a link to that file: you get the download prompt, and the browser stays on the current page!

Answer (score 2):

Call `window.open` like this (it works in all major browsers):

```
window.open(file, '_parent', 'download');
```

Comment: Check out Benjamin's answer below. More efficient. Better answer.